# Sort results in varchar column with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-postgresql, natural-sort

I have theses values in my table

```
id | NAME
1 | 20 MEGA
2 | 30 MEGA
3 | 10 MEGA
4 | 300 MEGA
5 | 100 MEGA
6 | 25 MEGA
```

What i want:

```
id | NAME
3 | 10 MEGA
1 | 20 MEGA
6 | 25 MEGA
2 | 30 MEGA
5 | 100 MEGA
4 | 300 MEGA
```

I tried this query:

select * from table_name ORDER BY "name" ASC

But returns

```
3   10 MEGA
5   100 MEGA
1   20 MEGA
6   25 MEGA
2   30 MEGA
4   300 MEGA
```

How can i do this?

Comment: If you have only the 'MEGA' suffix you can just remove it and cast to integer the order by expression. But... what if you have '1 GIGA' too?

Comment: if `10 MEGA` is something that can be semantically translated into `10` + `MEGA` then maybe the two needs to be in two separate columns. In which case you can write efficient queries.

Comment: `order by split_part("name", ' ', 1)::int, split_part("name", ' ', 2)`

Comment: You can find other duplicates under the [`[natural-sort] [postgresql]` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/natural-sort+postgresql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to ORDER BY the numbers specifically in the `"name"` column by treating them as an `int`. To do so, you'll want to ensure any non-digits are removed first using regexp_replace.

```
ORDER BY regexp_replace("name", '\D', '', 'g')::int ASC
```

You could take it a step further and convert empty values to `0` or `NULL`.